# Silverlight 5 "full access to the filesystem" in Mac?

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight 5 allows you to get full access to the local file system. Does anybody know if this feature is also available on the Mac OS X?

Comment: Here is the similar question and the answer
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522590/silverlight-5-trusted-mode-accessing-filesystem-and-local-drives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Trusted  applications are a Windows-only feature in Silverlight 5.
And only trusted applications can access the local file system.

Comment: That's not exactly true... You still can access files and folders through System.Io classes from mscorlib. Although you probably can't get information about available drives on Mac.