# Silverlight 5 Trusted Mode. Accessing FileSystem and Local drives 

Tags: windows, macos, out-of-browser, silverlight-5.0, elevated-privileges

Is there any way, any chance at all to access entire filesystem in SL app with elevated trust? 
That will work both in Windows and Mac? 
Through `AutomationFactory`,`PInvoke` or unmanaged code?
I need an app that could read local drives, folders and files.

UDP: Ok, seems it's possible to read folders and files using classes of `System.IO` from mscorlib. Although you still can't get information about local mounted drives. There is no `DriveInfo` in Silverlight's `mscorlib` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have an idea about this.

It is straightforward enough with Windows, to get the list of the local drives you can use `AutomationFactory`. There is plenty amount of examples if you google it. Search for something called SilverlightFileExplorer.

Now on a Mac you can use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories("/")` and then it gets all the folders in the root. Including Volumes folder which contains shortcuts to the local drives. I'm not an expert of Berkeley System Distribution (BSD) Unix filesystems, so I can't really promise that it would work on any Mac, but this approach works on mine.

I'm still playing around with that. When I get working prototype I'll probably share it through github or something.