# Can you enable trusted mode in browser for Mac Users in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, macos

I have a question around Trusted In Browser applications.  Are these applications supported on OSX?  My team has developed a large educational silverlight package that requires local storage.  We'd really like our users to be able to select the folder they save their files in.  There's instructions for how to enable this in Windows here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx  but no instructions I have found describing how you could enable this on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac you can use the System.IO libraries. Read [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522590/silverlight-5-trusted-mode-accessing-filesystem-and-local-drives) for more information.

Comment: I believe that's only for Out Of Browsers Silverlight applications.  I was referring to in browser applications.